# Why are questions with my ignored tags not hidden?

Tags: support, tags, user-interface, ignored-tags

Questions that are tagged with one of my "ignored" tags on Stack Overflow are hidden completely. On Server Fault, however, those questions are "lightened" to lower their contrast. Why is that?

Is it just because at first there were fewer questions on SF so it didn't make sense to hide some of them? Are there plans to apply the same logic to both sites (eg hide on both or "lighten" on both)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a user preference
`http://serverfault.com/users/USERID?tab=preferences#sort-top`

> Hide ignored tags.

Comment: Huh! I guess I must've turned that on so long ago on Stack Overflow that I'd forgotten about it! Thanks Ian.