# Why are ignored tags still showing up in my feed?

Tags: tags, discussion, ignored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are questions with my ignored tags not hidden?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4639/why-are-questions-with-my-ignored-tags-not-hidden)

Why aren't ignored tags hidden from my feed? Right now the only difference is that a different css class is applied to grey them out... Seems like it defeats the purpose. I want to remove topics I can't offer much perspective on :-)

Comment: There's an option for it in your profile.